# Cannot install libc6-devel-i386 on windows

Tags: i386

How to install the package on windows? I have seen a lot of Ubuntu guides but don't know how to install for windows

Comment: Windows and Linux (Ubuntu is a Linux distribution) are two *extremely* different operating systems. You can't use programs made for one on another. What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you think you need to use a Linux libc package on Windows?

Comment: I am following some create your own operating system tutorial on youtube

Comment: Then you basically have four choices: 1) Install Ubuntu on your system. 2) Install Ubuntu on a virtual machine. 3) Find a new tutorial that uses Windows as host for development. 4) Install an environment like Cygwin for development. Oh, and you really should get some theoretical background about operating systems first.

Comment: I am using cygwin but I cannot find that package

Answer (score -1):

You need libc6 header files from this library to include with your c++ programs that is not OS specific.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33482929)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).